# Python script works from IDE but not from terminal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, vlc, pulseaudio

The following python code works fine from Mu.
When run from terminal the following error message is received.

"vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused"

Is this some sort of python permissions problem?

```
import vlc
import time
import threading as th
from gpiozero import Button, LED
from signal import pause

buttons = [Button(2), Button(3), Button(4)]
LEDS = [LED(16), LED(21), LED(20)]

path = '/media/media/EMPTY/'
sounds = ['audiofileA.mp3', 'audiofileB.mp3', 'audiofileC.mp3']
Play = [False, False, False]
VOLUME = 100

def debounce(p):
    Play[p] = False
    LEDS[p].off()

def player(p):
    LEDS[p].on()
    print("Button " + str(p + 1) + " Pressed")
    global Play
    if(Play[p] == False):
        print("Playing " + str(p + 1))
        Play[p] = True
        player = vlc.MediaPlayer(path + sounds[p])
        vlc.libvlc_audio_set_volume(player, VOLUME)
        player.stop()
        player.play()
        S = th.Timer(0.5, debounce, [p])
        S.start()
    else:
        return

def button1_pressed():
    player(0)

buttons[0].when_pressed = button1_pressed

def button2_pressed():
    player(1)

buttons[1].when_pressed = button2_pressed

def button3_pressed():
    player(2)

buttons[2].when_pressed = button3_pressed

while True:
    continue
```

Comment: Well how are you running it at boot, and with what permission base.

Comment: If you're running something at asystem startup (which I assume is what you mean by "run from boot", perhaps you can clarify), it's likely that whatever your script tries to connect to hasn't finished initialising / starting up yet. Perhaps build in a delay?

Comment: pretty sure if you sleep for a minute or maybe only a few seconds between intializing the player and setting the volume ... or maybe even before initializing the player

Comment: @SharpDev At the moment I'm starting it with cron using the following.
"@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/media/python/Player.py >/home/media/logs/cronlog 2>&1"
I don't know what permission base that would be.

Comment: Don't do it from `cron`, use an `init.d` script. Then you have more control over the ordering, and you can ensure that it runs after the script that starts the audio server.

Comment: Alternatively you could put a loop around `player = vlc.MediaPlayer(path + sounds[p])` using `try/except`, to keep trying to connect until it succeeds.

Comment: The VLC player is not called until a button is pressed on the Raspberry Pi. At boot there are no errors, the cron log is empty. The error only appears in the log once a button is pressed (and every time thereafter).

Comment: I've experienced similar issues using a cron job accessing files in the /home/user directory... I recommend you make a folder in /usr/app or something similar (i.e. using the /usr/ directory) to hold your project and try using that in your cron job... I can't recall off top of my head if raspberry pie has a separate root user, if it does you could try there... But I think you should have success with `/usr/app/myscripts and files`

Comment: The error indicates that your script ran before the pulseaudio service started properly. The proper way to fix this is definetely a systemd service with a dependency on pulseaudio, but a simple time.sleep(5) will probably also do the job (even if just to confirm the issue).

Comment: make sure pulse audio is running and if its not, you can start it. Run the commands pulseaudio --check and pulseaudio --start. Pulse audio may not be running in boot as it may be using a different environment than Mu

Comment: On some distros the audio server isn't even started until a user logs into the GUI interactively, so unless you reconfigure you _can't_ play audio from software that isn't invoked from a GUI session. That's a system administration matter, not a development matter; how to do that reconfiguration is a question for your distro's documentation.